# SASS variable with @media in css not working

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

variables.scss:

```
$large-screen: 1200px;
$screen-large: #{($large-screen - 1)};
$large-down: 'screen and (max-width: #{$screen-large})';
@debug $screen-large;
```

In another scss file:

```
@import '../../styles/variables.scss';
@media #{$large-down} {
    my styling…
}
```

**Problem:** It doesn’t apply the "My styling" part. 
If I replace the `@media` line with `@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {` it does work.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Update:** I discovered that `$screen-large: #{($large-screen - 1)};` results in `"1200px - 1"` rather than `"1199px"`. Is there a way in SASS to make it do the calculation instead of take it as a string?

I've tried `$screen-large: calc($large-screen - 1);` but it still returns that whole line as a string rather than do the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

variables.scss:

```
$large-screen: 1200px;
$screen-large: ($large-screen - 1);  // Now it no longer interpolates to a string.
$large-down: 'screen and (max-width: #{$screen-large})';
```

In another scss file:

```
@import '../../styles/variables.scss';
@media #{$large-down} {
    my styling…
}
```